# How to contest a duplicate question when it is not a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076435/update-a-record-using-the-sum-of-its-value-and-another) is being marked as a duplicate. At one point in time I saw a link at the top stating something along the lines of "Maybe you can try explaining how this is not a duplicate" or something like that, and I can't find it now. Where does that link take you?

It's being marked as a duplicate because it's being taken by some that I'm trying to do a running total which already has an answer. I'm not. That's not the purpose of my table. I haven't even specified anywhere in my question I'm trying to calculate a running total. The 2 rows I'm taking the sums from don't have to be beside each other.

Comment: There is nothing to contest, your question was never closed as a duplicate.  A single vote from a single non-privileged user doesn't count, it takes five of them.

Comment: One day someone is going to have a similar question and will be marked as duplicate referencing this question.

Comment: This question about duplicates is a duplicate of a duplicate question about duplicates. That duplicate is another duplicate, with 2 duplicates one of which is another duplicate of the penultimate first duplicate.

Comment: @Tim I'm lost. Once again from the top? :p - on a side note, this being a dupe is satisfying on a deep OCD level.

Answer (score 5):

> It's being marked as a duplicate because it's being taken by some that I'm trying to do a running total which already has an answer. I'm not. That's not the purpose of my table. I haven't even specified anywhere in my question I'm trying to calculate a running total. The 2 rows I'm taking the sums from don't have to be beside each other.

Then simply *explain that in your question*.  Say that you're not asking for X, you're actually asking for Y.  That then makes it crystal clear that the question isn't a duplicate, and it can be reopened.

Note that you don't need to be stating *that* your question isn't a duplicate.  That doesn't mean anything to anyone.  You need to edit the question to make it clear(er) why your question is different, or in what way the duplicate question doesn't solve your problem.

All that said, you're question isn't even closed as a duplicate.  It has two pending close votes, one as a duplicate, one as "unclear".  So you should absolutely be editing the question to clarify it, but you should be doing that so that it doesn't get closed in the first place, not because it needs to be reopened.

Comment: That's why I came here. To prevent it from being closed. I don't see how people are taking it as a running total. It doesn't make sense to me. I'll try clarifying it some more.

Comment: @Luminous So you're drawing a ton of attention to your question so that all of those people can...not close it.  If you want all of us to not vote to close it you don't need to create a meta post.  If you want to know what you can do to improve the question, I've told you what you can do.  Whether you take my advice or not is entirely up to you.

Comment: That's why I came here. To get some advice on how I can clarify the question because the perceived context of those readers towards my question doesn't make much sense to me. The title might be off, but everything else about it is cut and dry to me. I guess I was premature in asking for help. I'm not trying to draw a ton of attention. Just some help on how I can clarify it. You've done some of that already. So thanks!